# Xamarin Form: Ios Toast Notification

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created a Toast notification in my Xamarin PCL project. I have created this control using [this](https://bykov.tech/2016/10/17/toast-message-for-xamarin-forms/). As soon as this toast message disappears my app becomes blank. I cannot figure out why? no exception from any where??

In Portable:

```
namespace ABC
{
        public interface IMessage
        {
            void LongAlert(string message);
            void ShortAlert(string message);
        }
}
```

In Droid:

```
public class MessageAndroid : IMessage
    {
        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

In Windows 10:

```
public class ToastNotificationManagerRenderer : IMessage
    {
        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            var notificationXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
            var toeastElement = notificationXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            toeastElement[0].AppendChild(notificationXml.CreateTextNode(message));
            var toastNotification = new ToastNotification(notificationXml);
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastNotification);
        }

        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            var notificationXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
            var toeastElement = notificationXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            toeastElement[0].AppendChild(notificationXml.CreateTextNode(message));
            var toastNotification = new ToastNotification(notificationXml);
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastNotification);
        }
    }
```

In Ios:

```
public class MessageIOS : IMessage
    {
        const double LONG_DELAY = 3.5;
        const double SHORT_DELAY = 2.0;

        NSTimer alertDelay;
        UIAlertController alert;

        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, LONG_DELAY);
        }
        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, SHORT_DELAY);
        }

        void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
        {
            alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
            {
                dismissMessage();
            });
            alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }

        void dismissMessage()
        {
            if (alert != null)
            {
                alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
            }
            if (alertDelay != null)
            {
                alertDelay.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

For Ios: I have tried this plugin also.[MessageBarLib](https://github.com/prashantvc/Xamarin.iOS-MessageBar). Code same as above in portable but in Ios -

```
public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            MessageBarManager.SharedInstance.ShowMessage("Success", message, MessageType.Success);

        }
```

But after exiting from above function, my app closes.

Comment: Ideally we could do with some code to look at, but I would suggest it is likely that when the modal notification is removed from view, the base UIViewController is running it's 'ViewWillAppear' or 'ViewDidLoad' methods and I'm hazarding a guess that you have something in them that it doesn't like. It'd be easier to confirm this if you could give us YOUR code examples rather than what you worked off of.

Comment: Does it close on every version? I.E. iOS, Android and Windows? I can see some places in your iOS class where it might get confused, but lets try and narrow this down a little more.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt It is happening in IOS only.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this for IOS:-

```
private const int Margin = 30;
private const int Height = 40;
private const int Width = 400;
private NSTimer _timer;

    public void ShowAlert(string message)
    {
        var toast = new MessageIOS();
        toast.Show(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View, message);
    }
    public MessageIOS()
    {
        _view = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 175, 240)
        };
        _view.Layer.CornerRadius = (nfloat)20.0;

        _label = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
            TextColor = UIColor.White
        };
        _view.AddSubview(_label);

    }

    public void Show(UIView parent, string message)
    {
        if (_timer != null)
        {
            _timer.Invalidate();
            _view.RemoveFromSuperview();
        }

        _view.Alpha = (nfloat)0.7;

        _view.Frame = new CGRect(
            (parent.Bounds.Width - Width) / 2,
            parent.Bounds.Height - Height - Margin,
            Width,
            Height);

        _label.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, Width, Height);
        _label.Text = message;

        parent.AddSubview(_view);

        var wait = 10;
        _timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), delegate {
            if (_view.Alpha <= 0)
            {
                _timer.Invalidate();
                _view.RemoveFromSuperview();
            }
            else
            {
                if (wait > 0)
                {
                    wait--;
                }
                else
                {
                    _view.Alpha -= (nfloat)0.05;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your comments and the code, I suspect that the dismissMessage()' is clearing all of the UIViewControllers that were put onto the stack by the 'PresentingViewController'. I suspect it's a bit of a bug, but If you try:

```
PresentingViewController.DismissViewController(true, null);
```

Instead of

```
alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
```

I suspect it should work correctly. If not then we could do with knowing a bit more about the design pattern you use in your iOS project to determine if you are presenting 'UIViewControllers' properly.